# Is there a way to use overlapping community clustering algorithms on igraph networks?

Tags: r, networking, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

I have a list object of igraph networks that I would like to apply an overlapping community algorithm to. I understand that `cluster_fast_greedy` and `cluster_edge_betweenness` in igraph are hierarchical algorithms but they do not seem to serve my purposes.

The OCG clustering function in the [linkcomm package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/linkcomm/index.html) seems to do just that. But it does not work on any of my igraph networks. Is there a way to use it or another overlapping clustering algorithm on my list of networks without having to rewrite the code that made the network objects?

Is there a way to use `getOCG_cluster()` or another overlapping clustering algorithm on an igraph network?

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work on any of my igraph networks"?    Do you get error messages?

Comment: I did when I used the typical indexing for an igraph nw to community plot. `getOCG.clusters(as_edgelist(listofgraphs3[[3]]))` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, there's a code for a custom overlapping communities function on an igraph wiki: http://igraph.wikidot.com/community-detection-in-r#toc0.

```
clique.community <- function(graph, k) {
   clq <- cliques(graph, min=k, max=k)
   edges <- c()
   for (i in seq_along(clq)) {
     for (j in seq_along(clq)) {
       if ( length(unique(c(clq[[i]], clq[[j]]))) == k+1 ) {
         edges <- c(edges, c(i,j)-1)
       }
     }
   }
   clq.graph <- simplify(graph(edges))
   V(clq.graph)$name <- seq_len(vcount(clq.graph))
   comps <- decompose.graph(clq.graph)

   lapply(comps, function(x) {
     unique(unlist(clq[ V(x)$name ]))
   })
}
```